# Use of certificate pinning and compatibility of Corporate MITMs

Tags: ios, ssl, afnetworking

I know Google uses Certificate Pinning, and can allow user installed Certs to override the pinning inorder for compatibility with some corporation MITM's. Can AFNetworking supports type of override?

Answer (score -2):

I found this resource that details how to do what I think you are asking using AFNetworking.

http://initwithfunk.com/blog/2014/03/12/afnetworking-ssl-pinning-with-self-signed-certificates/

Here is the relevant code example:

```
// This usually would be a subclass of AFHTTPSessionManager
AFHTTPSessionManager *client = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL sessionConfiguration:configuration];
client.securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];
client.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
```

The code is from AFNetworking 2.2.1, but should work for the most recent version.

Comment: I think you are missing one important point of my question is how do I allow a cert I side load to be used so to allow some some IT policies to replace my cert mid way.  i.e. allowing MITM on specific certs.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect what you are asking.

Comment: What's not clear it specifically ask at the end, does it support overrides.